# Output in GS accurate but multiple Quote marks being added to output when copy-pasted to a any text editor

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a Script by @Tanaike
[Concatenation of single quote marks Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124220/concatenation-of-single-quote-marks-google-script)

The output in Google sheets look correct but when I copy and paste the output into any other text editor there are multiple added `quote` marks

How do I keep this addition of `quote marks` from happening, I cannot see in the code anything that is causing this other than possible the use of `\n`

Thanks

Here is a google sheet with Script
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16MXnuMzjQErH3fxxmuwAXqmJ-6XB_HbwrnHQhS1VeyU/edit?usp=sharing

Image of the column from google Sheet

[image]

Options List when pasted into a text editor

```
"option {
label: ""label_1"";
selector: [""time you personally have been engaged with uscan""=""Arts""];
}"
"option {
label: ""label_2"";
selector: [""time you personally have been engaged with uscan""=""Children’s 
Issues""];
}"
"option {
label: ""label_3"";
selector: [""time you personally have been engaged with uscan""=""Coaching""];
}"
etc..
```

GS

```
function OptionsList() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OptionList");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, 3).getValues();
  values = values.filter(function(e){return e[0] && e[1] && e[2]});
  var result = [];
  //Add items to results
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){ // Modified
  result[i] = ["option {\nlabel: \"" + values[i][1] + "\";\n" + "selector: [\"" + values[i][0] + "\"=\"" + values[i][2] + "\"];\n}"]; // Modified
  }

 //Post back to column 4 starting on row 2
 sheet.getRange(2, 4, result.length, 1).clear
 sheet.getRange(2, 4, result.length, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Is there no other way to copy the entire range other than one cell at a time from the `formula bar`?

Comment: I will give it a try. thanks

Comment: I am completely confounded by the downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will output your `output list` to a single cell `E2` so you only have to copy from the formula bar once

I think I got your ranges correct

```
function OptionsListToCell() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OptionList");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 4, lr, 4).getValues();
  values = values.filter(function(e){return e[0]});
  var temp = ""

  //Add items to temp
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){ // Modified
    temp = temp +  [values[i] + "\n"];  
  }

  var cell = sheet.getRange("E2");
  //Clear cell
  cell.activate();
  sheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  //Write value to cell
  cell.setValue(temp);
}
```

Comment: xyz, I see I do not have enough rep. points to comment on your answer, but very nice addition you made

Answer (score 0):

I used `Jersy One` solution to add the output to an HTML window

This is the solution I am using but I am giving credit to Jersy One

```
function OptionsList_POPUP() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Opt");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr, 3).getValues();
  values = values.filter(function(e){return e[0] && e[1] && e[2]});
  var result = [];

  //Add items to results
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++){ // Modified
     result[i] = ["option {<br />label: \"" + values[i][1] + "\";<br />" + "selector: [\"" + values[i][0] + "\"=\"" + values[i][2] + "\"];<br />}<br />"];
  }

  var temp = ""
  for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){ // Modified
    temp = temp +  [result[i] + "\n"];
  }

  //Output to Html
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
              .createHtmlOutput(temp)
              .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
              .setWidth(510)
              .setHeight(500);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Opt');

  //Post back to column 4 starting on row 2
  //sheet.getRange(2, 4, result.length, 1).clear
  //sheet.getRange(2, 4, result.length, 1).setValues(result);
}
```